# multiple views in asp.net 

Tags: asp.net

How can I create multiple views in asp.net?  I'm using visual C#.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by view? Are you using ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Do you mean the [MultiView-Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227665.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

use multi-view control. add views to it.. make different views active when you need. this will help in creating different view in same asp page.